# Kernel version in Loki (0.4)? Support for Atheros WiFi hardware

Tags: networking, kernel, release-loki

I recently purchased a new laptop by Acer, part of the Aspire E15 lineup, and it seems that the WiFi hardware is not supported with the kernel that is being used by Freya.

Since Elementary is an Ubuntu-based OS, I searched on Ubuntu forums, and [after a lot of digging](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2304250) managed to backport the driver from a higher kernel version.

However, somewhere in the thread, it's mentioned that Ubuntu now supports [QCA9377 and ath10k by default.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2300861)

So, I was hoping to find out, if the next version of Elementary OS (Loki, 0.4) would include support "out of the box" for Atheros WiFi hardware?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elementary OS is based on Ubuntu Longterm Releases. Loki will therefore be based on Ubuntu 16.04. Ubuntu 16.04 will have the Linux Kernel 4.4 as base as [announced](http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-16-04-lts-xenial-xerus-will-be-powered-by-linux-kernel-4-4-lts-496675.shtml). So for the first release of elementary OS, this kernel will be the base.

That said, your hardware should be supported in Loki, yes.

Answer (score 1):

As bigbang mention above that elementary OS is based on LTS Ubuntu, so your card should work. Alternatively, you can compile the kernel 4.4 from source yourself. Use menuconfig for simple configuration and under device drivers menu, find wireless card support and look for atheros.

Or you can use [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1484159) based on your current kernel. I think it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am still relatively new to Linux, and this is the first I've heard about menuconfig. I read about it, and I didn't know kernel configuration could be done with this! I understood it to be a somewhat more complex process, which is why I was asking about native support in the first place. So thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The features and kernel for 0.4 are [still very much in flux](https://plus.google.com/+CassidyJames/posts/GzwFLE2mvH5), so there's no way to say for sure what it will or won't support.

That said, Ubuntu periodically releases updates to the [hardware enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) in 14.04, and these updates generally make their way to Elementary 0.3.x pretty soon after Ubuntu releases them. So, 0.3.x may eventually get the kernel/driver updates you backported.

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just install the driver by building it with git.

https://github.com/ajaybhatia/Qualcomm-Atheros-QCA9377-Wifi-Linux

If your unsure how to do it, you tube how to build with gitclone.